# Set the polygon collider according to line's shape with line renderer drawing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal is to be able to draw various lines using line renderer component, add a collider to that line and a rigidbody.

I use this code to draw the line and set edge collider`s points of that line:

```
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        poinsOfLine.Add (mousePos);
        line.positionCount = poinsOfLine.Count;
        line.SetPosition (poinsOfLine.Count - 1, poinsOfLine [poinsOfLine.Count - 1]);
        if (poinsOfLine.Count > 1)
        {
            collider.points = poinsOfLine.ToArray();
            collider.enabled = true;
        }
```

I can use edge colliders for this task, but they don`t collide with each other:
[image]

Or I can use polygon colliders, but the fill the whole shape:
[image]

I do not want the lines to be filled like in the second screenshot, I want collider to follow the shape of the line like in the first screenshot, but with polygon collider, not edge collider, because edge colliders do not collide with each other.

I tried setting the points of the polygon collider myself like this:

```
PolygonCollider2D polyColl = newDrawie.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
Vector2[] polyPoints = new Vector2[poinsOfLine.Count * 2];
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < polyPoints.Length; i += 2) 
{
    //sumVector += collider.points[i / 2];
    //numberOfPoints++;
    polyPoints[i] = collider.points[i / 2];
    polyPoints[j] = collider.points[i / 2] + Vector2.up * 0.1f;
    j += 2;
}
polyColl.SetPath(0, polyPoints);
```

But it does not give me the result I want.

How can I make polygon collider follow the shape of the lines like in the first screenshot?

Comment: sorry I can't figure out what you are asking. have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the post, and tried to explain my problem better

Comment: Did you use rigidbody2D?

Comment: Yes, Rigidbody2D

Comment: if I remember correctly 2 edge colliders do not collider with each other. they are designed to collide with solid shapes like polygon collider. so you can change your edge colliders to box colliders 2d with a small width

Comment: Hmm, but then I won`t be able to set points, and will have to add lots of box colliders

Comment: Another thought, box collider is more expensive than circle or sphere collider. you can keep the edge colliders, but also add some circle or sphere colliders at different joints

Comment: This could work